# How to translate particle rendering from CUDA code to OpenCL kernels if header files for kernels can't have function qualifiers in them?

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I am trying to take apart a simple particle collision OpenGL programm in order to make it use OpenCL 2.0 instead of CUDA for GPU calculations. However, my lack of experience with OpenCL ended up leaving me stuck on distribution of memory between host and kernel, apparently quite different here from what I know about CUDA.

Code fragment below is used in my `renderScene()` function now located in `main.cu`

```
  glColor3f(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.5f);
  if (g_numParticles > 0)
  {
    int blockSize = 32;
    int gridSize = 1000;
    int numElemsPerThread = (g_numParticles + blockSize * gridSize - 1) / (blockSize * gridSize);

    cudaMemcpy(g_particlesGPU, g_particles, g_numParticles * sizeof(Particle), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(g_timesGPU, g_times, g_numParticles * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(g_normalsGPU, normals, g_m * sizeof(Point), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(g_centersGPU, centers, g_m * sizeof(Point), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(g_tang1GPU, tang1, g_m * sizeof(Point), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(g_tang2GPU, tang2, g_m * sizeof(Point), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(g_wGPU, w, g_m * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(g_hGPU, h, g_m * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    float4* positions;
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &g_verticesCuda, 0);
    size_t num_bytes;
    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&positions, &num_bytes, g_verticesCuda);

    moveAndDrawParticles<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(g_numParticles, g_particlesGPU, g_timesGPU, g_m, g_normalsGPU, g_centersGPU, g_tang1GPU, g_tang2GPU, g_wGPU, g_hGPU, t, positions, numElemsPerThread);
    //std::cout << cudaGetLastError() << std::endl;

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &g_verticesCuda, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_vertices);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 16, 0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, g_numParticles);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    cudaMemcpy(g_particles, g_particlesGPU, g_numParticles * sizeof(Particle), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(g_times, g_timesGPU, g_numParticles * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i = 0; i < g_numParticles; ++i)
    {
      if (g_times[i] - t < 0)
      {
        g_particles[i] = g_particles[g_numParticles - 1];
        g_times[i] = g_times[g_numParticles - 1];
        --g_numParticles;
        --i;
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, here I copy particle information on CUDA device, run `moveAndDrawParticles` kernel function, synchronize and copy back to host. Translation of this part seems manageable enough: slap some boilerplate code from documentation to initialize OpenCL with all the necessary buffers, replace cudaMemcpy with `clEnqueueRead(Write)Buffer()`, swap `moveAndDrawParticles()` for a dedicated `kernel.cl` that will be compiled using my OCL SDK.

However, the latest turns out to be the point where problems make themselves visible.
Besides `main.cu`, I use only two files - `particle.cu` and its header, `particle.h`, which you can see below

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
struct Point
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  CUDA_CALLABLE Point(float _x, float _y, float _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}
};
struct Particle
{
  Point pos;
  Point v;
  CUDA_CALLABLE Particle(Point _pos, Point _v) : pos(_pos), v(_v) {}
};
__global__ void moveAndDrawParticles(int n, Particle *particles, float *g_times, int m, const Point *normals, const Point *centers, const Point *tang1, const Point *tang2,
  const float *w, const float *h, float dt, float4 *positions, int numElemsPerThread);
```

Both Point and Particle structures implemented in particle.cu are used in the host-based part of the main.cu before anything is written to the GPUs. What is more, `CUDA_CALLABLE` here stands for `__host__ __device__` and OpenCL has no similar qualifiers.
The last problem here is in the `moveAndDrawParticles()` function - if I turn particle.cu file into OpenCL kernel, it will be necessary to preface every input variable with an appropriate qualifier, which appears impossible to do in the header file - or, for that matter, anywhere outside of kernels themselves.

I would be thankful for any help in clearing up these translation issues, and any pointers to errors in my reading of OpenCL documentation would also be appreciated. As the actual rendering code is quite verbose by necessity, I've omitted plenty of it in hopes that above snippets will be enough for a reasonable impression, if not a readily runnable programm.

Comment: This question makes no sense. Your CUDA code is using C++ language features (like member functions in classes). OpenCL is C99 based. There are no classes and structures cannot have member functions. There is no "translation" for insoluble problems like this

Comment: OpenCL does support limited C++ features if it is AMD GPU with high enough version support. But it is needed to build those objects with a kernel and send construction data through arrays-only(kernel parameters). Maybe only Sycl can share host object definitions with a GPU.